# Hotkey to run the entire script

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a hotkey (or can I create one) to run the active entire script with only one hotkey? Currently I have to use `CTRL+A` (select all lines) and `ALT+ENTER` (run current selection).

For example, in MATLAB I could use the `F5` hotkey to run all the script.

**Edit**:
I use Rstudio

Comment: For RStudio we have [Ctrl+Alt+R](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts)

Comment: If you like to use the `F5` then we can [Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts), Tools -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts...

Answer (score 1):

Two items from the `Source` pull-down menu (Windows version):

[image]

Comment: The problem with Source is that I don't get the same output as the Run function. Don't know why.

Comment: And with `Source with Echo`? What are the differences?